# How and why does this output 3 lines of code?

Tags: c

I am trying to study for a test on C, and I am not understanding what this code does, and why it outputs what it outputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int a, int d, int b, int c);

int main(){

    int a = 1, b = 3, c = 2, d =4;

    a = f(d, a, f(a, c, b+c, d), a+c);

    printf("a=%d b=%d c=%d d=%d\n", a, b, c, d);

    return 0;
}

int f(int a, int d, int b, int c){

    int sum;

    b = a + c; 

    sum = b - c;

    d = sum + d;

    printf("a=%d b=%d c=%d d=%d\n", a, b, c, d);

    if (sum > a*c)
        return a*c;

    if (sum <= b*c)
        return sum+a;
    
    return a*b;
}
```

When I enter the code into VsCode and run it, this is what it outputs:

```
a=1 b=5 c=4 d=3
a=4 b=7 c=3 d=5
a=8 b=3 c=2 d=4
```

Comment: There are 2 calls to `f`, which each call `printf` once. Plus one more `printf` in `main` - so what exactly is the confusion?

Comment: Replace your prints: `printf("a=%d b=%d c=%d d=%d ... in %s()\n", a, b, c, d, __func__);`

Comment: perhaps better: `int tmp = f(a, c, b+c, d); a = f(d, a, tmp, a+c);`

Comment: What do you expect it to output? What part of the code, specifically, do you not understand?

Answer (score 2):

Each call to `main` prints a line, and each call to `f` prints a line.

```
    printf("a=%d b=%d c=%d d=%d\n", a, b, c, d);
```

`main` is called once, implicitly, when the program starts.

Then `main` calls `f` twice.

```
    a = f(d, a, f(a, c, b+c, d), a+c);
        ^       ^
        |       first
   second
```

When you're confused about things like this, add extra print statements. For example...

```
    puts("This print is from f");
    printf("a=%d b=%d c=%d d=%d\n", a, b, c, d);
```